# Difference between variance of a set of data points and variance of a series

Tags: time-series, variance

A stationary time series is supposed to have a variance that is a not a function of time. That is the variance is constant. My question is how to calculate the variance of a series? I understand how to calculate the variance of a set of data points where the set is fixed.

Comment: You're dealing with the variance of a collection (a sequence) of related random variables . If you can show that the variance of $Y_t$ and $Y_{t+s}$ are the same for all $t$ and $s$ then the series will be variance stationary.

Comment: It all depends on how the series is given to you.  The "variance" you are referring to is a *theoretical* one concerning the common variance of each random variable in the series.  So, to make your question understandable, please edit it to include a statement of everything relevant you know or assume about those random variables.